# "Maven is on version" provides the error "Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly"

Tags: java, maven

When I run `echo "Maven is on version`mvn -v`"`, the following error occurs:

> Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.   We cannot execute
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java Maven is on version

I tried different solutions explained in other threats, however none worked so far:

I set JAVA_HOME (`/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre`) in the following places `/etc/profile.d/jdk.sh`, `etc/enviroment`, `bashrc`.

`echo $JAVA_HOME` gives:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
```

`echo $PATH` outputs:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

So, I cannot figure out why Maven version checking points to inexisting folder `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `JAVA_HOME` through the below commands

```
JAVA_HOME=jdk-install-dir
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```

I get this from [Oracle page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/821-0917/inst_set_jdk_korn_bash_t/index.html).

Comment: Thanks. I did it. Anyway I get `user@user-HP-EliteBook-8460p:/etc$ echo "Maven is on version `mvn -v`"Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java
Maven is on version`